# Shouldn’t the tag-length limit be relaxed for Portuguese?

Tags: support, tags

#### Edited to add:

> I’m not so concerned about any particular tag as I am about the issue that things often take more space in Portuguese than they do in English, and that therefore using a tag length limit based on English does not make sense when using Portuguese for creating tags.

---

In composing [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/534/38), I (felt that I) needed to make a tag for transatlantic differences, one corresponding to [the ***transatlantic-differences*** tag from ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transatlantic-differences), but this time in Portuguese.

However, the 26-character limit on the length of tags stopped me: at 28 characters, [diferenças-transatlânticas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferen%c3%a7as-transatl%c3%a2nticas) is now too long. Similarly [questões-transatlânticas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest%c3%b5es-transatl%c3%a2nticas) suffers from the same problem.

I was therefore forced to use [assuntos-transatlânticos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assuntos-transatl%c3%a2nticos), which is not as good of a tag.

The 26-character limit might make sense for English, but for Portuguese it quickly becomes at least onerous and perhaps odious, as the example given above illustrates.

Besides mandatory matters of concordance of gender and number which push the edges, there is also the issue that Portuguese cannot form noun–noun compounds as English can; instead it must have the preposition *de* between them, possibly with a contracted article depending.

Could we please get this length restricted fixed in a way that is respectful of the Portuguese language?  Right now, it is tuned for English and it just does not work for Portuguese.  One should not be penalized for using tags in Portuguese, and right now that’s what’s happening.

See also [this related question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259589/153355) and its proposed solution.

---

I have changed the tag to the suggested [diferença-transatlântica](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferen%c3%a7a-transatl%c3%a2ntica).

Comment: What would be the differences when using [tag:diferenças-transatlânticas] or [tag:regionalismo]?

Comment: @BlasSoriano The former would be for things that vary between one side of the Atlantic and the other, while the latter seems a much more general matter but which is probably more restricted in geography. I guess we could have [tag:diferenças-pe-pb] but that’s very ugly.

Comment: Would you like [tag:diferença-continental]? or [tag:diferença-transatlântica]?

Comment: @BlasSoriano I’m not so concerned about any particular tag as I am about the issue that things often take more space in Portuguese than they do in English, and that therefore using the same length limit based on English does not make sense when using Portuguese.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Maybe the issue is related to how often english speakers are more permisive when shortening words than portuguese (or spanish). For example, in english a "telephone" turned into "phone".

Comment: [This request for Stack Exchange in general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags) (declined). Also declined [on Gaming](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-limit-to-30-characters) with the justification that “the number of characters in the tags is a hard limit that cannot be changed without a significant overhaul”, but that was 4 years ago.

Comment: @Gilles It’s because of database schema, I’m sure.

Comment: @tchrist Sure. That's something they can change. It's not just one value in a configuration file but it's not the end of the world either. They already made a bigger change when they allowed non-ASCII tags (the original encoding of question tags used the characters `à` and `é` to delimit tag names!).